# RichHtmlEditor html property, to create default HTML content for a template, not working in SharePoint 2010

Tags: enterprise-wiki, richhtmlfield, customization

I've been developing a custom page layout to associate with the enterprise wiki content type in SharePoint 2010. The default comes with a RichHtmlEditor Field control. These field controls have an html property that is **supposed** to allow for default content to be placed in the editing box before the user touches it. I'd like to use this as a template of sorts.

It doesn't work however, and I'm all stumped for ideas. I've scoured up and down. It should work and none of the other field control properties seem to prohibit it. Html editing, everything else is enabled. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

In what I knew would be an obvious answer, the answer is enclose the markup in html tags in the html property.